# Loading specific area from an osm.pbf file into Maperitive

Tags: latitude-longitude, mapping, command-line, boundaries, maperitive

Is there a way to download a specific longtitude / latitude boundary area (a city) from a country osm.pbf file in Maperitive? In my case I am trying to load Greater Sydney from http://download.geofabrik.de/australia-oceania/australia.html I would like to use Maperitive because I have a particular .mrules I like to use